# Git: Keep local repository current with origin -- merge changes locally only -- never pushing changes back

Tags: git

My shop has a goofy setup where one person code reviews and pushes, while everyone else pulls, makes changes locally, then sends changes to the one guy for review and then push.

We all keep two local branches, "main" and "work" ("main" is static and we work in "work").

I need to know how execute the following steps:
1) Replace my "main" with the origin
2) Merge my changes from "work" into the newly updated "main"
3) Copy "main" back into "work"

The steps can be in any order, but I need to accomplish the basic idea of keeping up-to-date and working locally. I've been reading over the documentation, but I'm terrified to make a mistake. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be terrified of making a mistake.  Set up some test repositories and see how things work before you work with your production code.

> Replace my "main" with the origin

Assuming that your local `main` branch matches a remote `main` branch, you should simply be able to:

```
git checkout main
git pull
```

This will bring your local branch up-to-date with the remote branch.

> Merge my changes from "work" into the newly updated "main" and Copy "main" back into "work"

You said earlier that you don't make any changes to your "main" branch.

Having imported remote changes into your local `main` branch, you would merge them into your `work` branch like this:

```
git checkout work
git merge main
```

This is a pretty typical workflow: you would see something almost exactly like this if you were tracking code from an upstream source and maintaining a local set of patches.

Comment: Since *work* is a private branch, it may be worthwhile to pull changes in using `rebase` to keep history cleaner and more linear.

Answer (score -1):

one thing before answering the original question:  look into http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/
it is a hosted code review that simplifies a lot of the "who can land code in master and who does reviews" workflow.

back on topic, let's start with a few assumptions:

- you have in your working copy, two branches, 'main' and 'work'
- 'main' tracks origin/main, 'work' is local only and never gets pushed to the origin server
- let's call the review guy's remote 'review-guy'

here's the workflow:

1. remote guy lands stuff in origin
2. everyone wants to pull those changes in, `git fetch origin`
3. let's assume that it was a fast forward, so you can just merge the branch

   - `git checkout main`
   - `git merge origin/main`
4. there are a few alternatives to achieve the same result as 2/3, but i prefer to separate them so that i have more flexibility, although this one assumes that you originally set up main to track origin/main

   - `git checkout main`
   - `git pull --rebase`
5. now to update your work branch, this replays your changes on top of the new master, giving you the opportunity to work out any conflicts along the way

   - `git checkout work`
   - `git rebase -i master`
6. send your changes back to the review guy, something to this effect, you probably already have this part figured out.

   - `git push review-guy work:my-new-work-as-a-branch`